# Apache Phoenix DAO Testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, hbase, apache-phoenix

I need to test my DAO Layer (writen in Spring JDBC) that uses Apache Phoenix (SQL layer over HBase) as datasource.

I don't have much experience with testing databases. I made some research and I know that most common aproach is to use InMemory database but in this particular case I cannot use InMemory db cause Phoenix has some differences in SQL dialect.
So my question is what is the best aproach in this case to write integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer one IT test case org.apache.phoenix.end2end.QueryIT in apache phoenix code for writing your own